# Rails Minitest with Capybara, how get assert_select "button", "label" to work correctly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, minitest

In a (non-capybara-enabled) IntegrationTest, THIS assertion works:

```
assert_select "button", "Update"
```

for a page containing:

`... <button name="button" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update Account</button> ...`

I need Capybara for some of the IntegrationTest tests.

How do I perform the same assertion (e.g., simply assert there is a button with the text Update) when Capybara::Minitest::Assertions are included?

I added Capybara to test_helper.rb as shown below; now, that same assertion now throws this error:

```
TypeError: no implicit conversion of String into Hash
```

If I change the format of the assertion to:

```
assert_select "button", text: "Update Account"
```

it now throws this failure:

```
expected to find select box "button" that is not disabled but there were no matches
```

If I change the format of the assertion to:

```
assert_selector "button", text: "Update Account"
```

it now throws this failure:

```
expected to find css "button" but there were no matches
```

```
# test_helper.rb
require 'capybara/rails'
require 'capybara/minitest'

class ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  include Devise::Test::IntegrationHelpers
  include FactoryBot::Syntax::Methods
  # Make the Capybara DSL available in all integration tests
  include Capybara::DSL
  include Capybara::Minitest::Assertions  #### THIS LINE changes minitest assert_select #####

  # Reset sessions and driver between tests
  teardown do
    Capybara.reset_sessions!
    Capybara.use_default_driver
  end
end
```

Comment: Don't mix Capybara into `ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest`. You want to have a fast and light test class for "pure" integration tests and a separate class for testing user interaction.  If you're using Rails 5.17+ you have [ActionDispatch::SystemTestCase](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1.7/classes/ActionDispatch/SystemTestCase.html) which does exactly this. You can even generate [system tests](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#system-testing). If you're stuck on an older version create a subclass of `ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest` that you base your system tests on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want

```
assert_selector :button, "Update Account"
```

BUT you also need to use the Capybara methods for session control, `visit`, etc -- Capybara doesn't use the `get`, `post` etc responses from the integration tests.